# Error on instance DataBase - Enterprise Library

Tags: asp.net, oracle, enterprise-library

I trying compile one program legacy on my company, but on instance the database ... get this error :

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJY7h.png)

Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key ""

[Exeption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKKfh.png)

Please, help me

This is the code.

```
Private Function getUserInfoCode(ByVal user As String) As Dictionary(Of String, String) Implements IDataAccessLayer.getUserInfoCode
    Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing
    Dim db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance(Of EntLibData.Database)()
    ds = db.ExecuteDataSet("IDV_AUTH.IDV_TRAER_USU", user.ToUpper)
    Dim datos As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    For Each usu As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

        datos.Add("USUARIO", usu.Item("USU_USUARIO").ToString())
        datos.Add("INTENTOS", usu.Item("USU_INT_INGRESO").ToString())
        datos.Add("ESTADO", usu.Item("USU_ESTADO").ToString())

    Next

    Return datos
End Function
```

Comment: added the code line

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a Oracle Database?